# Understanding the indefinite integral (without reference to derivatives)

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

As I understand it, given some function $f$ integrable on $[a,b]$, we can define *an* indefinite integral of $f$ to be a function $F$ such that $$F(x)=\int_{n}^{x}f(t)dt,$$ where $n$ is some chosen fixed value on the $x$-axis such that $a \leq n \leq b$, and $x$ is a variable value varying between $n$ and $b$ inclusive.

We notice that aslong as $a \neq b$, there is an endless amount of different indefinite integral functions $F$ we can create for $f$, each one created by choosing a different value of $n$.

We call the set of all possible functions $F$ we can can create this way *the* indefinite integral of $f$, and denote it $$\int f(t)dt$$

Is my view of the indefinite integral correct? Am I on the right track? Or is there a fundamental misunderstanding somewhere in my explanation?
If this explanation is false, please explain why without assuming any knowledge of differential calculus; since the book I go through teaches integration before differentiation, I have only so far learnt about definite integrals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's close enough to right for your stage of learning. There are a few subtleties that can come later.

Doing integration first (which is where Archimedes started) you are setting yourself up for the fundamental theorem of calculus: when you learn about differentiation and then differentiate any one of those indefinite integrals you get the integrand.

Comment: I know that this isn't exactly related to the question I asked but more about the subtleties you mentioned: when we say that the indefinite integral is the set of all possible functions $F$ we can create, would it be inaccurate to view each function $F$ in the indefinite integral set as itself a set of definite integral values (i.e, the ordinate set of $F$)? Then we could say that the indefinite integral is the set of all possible definite integrals we can create within the function's interval of integration.

Comment: @MahdiRkioui Yes. Your definition computes the value of each of the indefinite integrals at each point as a definite integral. That's not the subtlety I had in mind. Eventually you will see that you could add any constant to one of your indefinite integrals and get another function with the same derivative, but you might not be able to get the new function in the way you propose because the constant was too large.

Comment: OK, so the derivative definition is more robust than my definition.. and to clarify, we *can't* interpret the indefinite integral as the set of all possible definite integrals values we can obtain by evaluating definite integrals of $f$ with upper and lower bounds somewhere in $[a,b]$?

Comment: @MahdiRkioui That's right, but it's a small point that you should not let color your correct understanding.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot.