# "Any two indefinite integrals of $f$ differ from each other by a definite integral of $f$" Is my explanation of this property correct?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I'm trying to make sure I have a good understanding of the fact that any two indefinite integrals of a function differ from each other by a constant value (specifically by a certain definite integral of the function).

Does the explanation I provide below display a correct understanding of the property?

Let $f$ be a function integrable over $[a,b]$, where $a\neq b$.

Let $n$ & $q$ be chosen fixed values in $[a,b]$ such that $n < q$.

Thus we can define two indefinite integrals of $f$, $N$ & $Q$, such that:
$$N(x)=\int_{n}^{x}f(t)dt\\\\Q(x)=\int_{q}^{x}f(t)dt$$
where $x$ is a variable value varying between $n$ & $b$ inclusive in the case of $N$ and varying between $q$ & $b$ inclusive in the case of $Q$.

Observe that, $\forall x\in[q,b]$,
$$N(x)-Q(x)=\int_{n}^{q}f(t)dt$$

In other words, for all $x$-values shared by the domain of $N$ & the domain of $Q$, the value of $N$ at $x$ differs from the value of $Q$ at that same $x$ by a fixed, constant amount. Namely, by $\int_{n}^{q}f(t)dt$.

Why does this property hold?

It follows from the definition of $N$, and the additive property of definite integrals, that for any $N(x)$ such that $x\in[q,b]$, we have:
$$N(x)=\int_{n}^{x}f(t)dt=\int_{n}^{q}f(t)dt+\int_{q}^{x}f(t)dt$$

Furthermore, it follows from the definition of $Q$ that, for any $Q(x)$ such that $x\in[q,b]$, we have:
$$Q(x)=\int_{q}^{x}f(t)dt$$

Thus we have
$$N(x)=\int_{n}^{q}f(t)dt+Q(x)$$

Rearranging, we find that
$$N(x)-Q(x)=\int_{n}^{q}f(t)dt$$
Thus, the property holds $\forall x\in[q,b]$.

Finally, notice that this property holds for *any* two indefinite integrals of $f$; all possible choices of $n,q\in[a,b]$ correspond to all possible pairs of indefinite integrals we can create $[a,b]$.

Comment: "the value of $N$ at $x$ is greater than the value of $Q$ at the same $x$" is not necessarily right as $\int_n^q f(f)\,\text{d}t$ might be negative. You might want to change the wording to "the value of $N$ at $x$ differs from the the value $Q$ at the same $x$"

Comment: @stange Ok, thanks, I will update it. Is it correct to imagine that we'd have a negative integral if, for example, the values of $f$ were negative over $[n,q]$ (i.e.. the graph of $f$ is below the $x$-axis)? I am trying to think of some concrete examples where the integral would be negative.

Comment: Yes, that would be true since the integral is positive, in the sense that for $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $f\geq 0$ we have $\int_a^b f(x)\,\text{d}x \geq 0$ (assuming the integral exist). Hence, by linearity the integral is negative for a fully negative function. The easiest example would be $f\equiv -c$ for some constant $c\geq 0$. Then $\int_a^b f(x)\,\text{d}x = (a-b)c \leq 0$.

Comment: I understand, thanks.

Comment: The proof is more concise by invoking the fundamental theorem of calculus. Let's call $F$ an antiderivative of $f$. Then, $N(x) - Q(x) = (F(x)-F(n)) - (F(x)-F(q)) = F(q)-F(n) = \int_n^qf(t)\mathrm{d}t = const$.

Comment: @Abezhiko I haven't yet learnt about the FTC so I'm unable to use it in a proof.

Comment: @DavidK I know that down the line indefinite integrals are defined differently using derivatives, but I haven't learnt that definition yet.. So what you're saying is that there are indefinite integrals of $f$ that we *can't* define the way I've defined them, and so I  *haven't* accounted for all possible indefinite integrals of $f$ in my explanation? And the point is that any two indefinite integrals of $f$ don't necessarily differ by a definite integral of $f$ but they do all differ by some constant value?

Comment: Also, the book I use (Apostol) defines them this way, because integration is taught before differentiation. In the book Apostol doesn't say that this property as I have described it is true, he says that this property implies that any two indefinite integrals of $f$ differ by a constant, as you have said. When I tried to fill in the details I must've assumed that that constant he was talking about was a definite integral, because it seemed to make sense with the definition given.

Comment: Yes, that's the book I use. I must've gotten ahead of myself trying to figure out what *the* indefinite integral of $f$ is. I actually created a post on my understanding of the definition a few days ago: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4671596/understanding-the-indefinite-integral-without-reference-to-derivatives In that post, Ethan Bolker seems to say the same thing that you do about the definition. I suppose I should've taken into account the fact that my definition is incomplete.

Comment: @DavidK I've edited my post to reflect what you've told me, have I got things right?

Comment: I have deleted several comments including one I wrote before I knew which book to look at and a couple that were made redundant when I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From comments, I learned that you are using Tom Apostol, *Calculus I*. I am guessing second edition (which is the edition I own).

As far as I could find, the term *indefinite integral* is introduced in section 2.18 and all examples of indefinite integrals have the form you use in your question.
So although some other authors use the term *indefinite integral* differently,
that is how Apostol uses it in *Calculus I* and your question should be read the way he uses it there.

(So my early comments about indefinite integrals -- where I had in mind that two indefinite integrals of $f$ might differ by more than the largest indefinite integral of $f$ -- might have been appropriate in some other context, but in this specific context, they were not.)

I that light I think what you have done is fine. You were very careful (maybe even more careful than Apostol in section 2.18).

Note that elsewhere you may see the term *indefinite integral of $f$* used differently than in Apostol's book.
It may refer to the family of functions containing all primitives of $f$
(Apostol defines *primitives* in section 5.3)
or it may be used interchangeably with *antiderivative*
(which Apostol uses interchangeably with *primitive*).
This is one reason why knowing your definitions -- and knowing which definitions apply in a particular context -- is important!
I raise the points in these paragraphs not with the intent to confuse you, but in an attempt to avoid having you encounter these slightly different definitions elsewhere without having been warned that such a thing might happen.

---

Collecting some thoughts from comments of mine that probably should have been answers:

I did not find a formal definition of indefinite integral anywhere in Apostol, but there is a statement that an expression such as $\int_a^x f(x)\,dx$ for constant $a$ is "sometimes" called an indefinite integral of $f$, and the idea seems to be that only such expressions are called indefinite integrals. Later, Apostol formally defines an *antiderivative* of $f$ to be a function whose derivative is $f$ (that is, $\int f(x)\,dx$ for a particular choice of integration constant). And you are right, that can only occur later because it requires the definition of a derivative.

Comment: Oh.. is what I said in the edit wrong then?

Comment: I misled you earlier, sorry. If you were reading some other book then the edit might be correct! But in this case I think you were right the first time.

Comment: Oh, ok, I'll delete the edit then. Thank you very much for the help.